# ActionBar throws NullPointerException in setDrawerListener

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying create an CustomActionBar with ActionBarDrawerToggle on Android v7. When I execute my project and try opened the Activity does throws an exception NullPointeException in this line: `setDrawerListener(tg);`.

Here how I am trying.

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import br.com.williarts.batalhajuridica.R;
import br.com.williarts.batalhajuridica.frags.PerfilFrag;

public class CustomDrawerLayout extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
    private ActionBar ab;
    private DrawerLayout dl;
    private ListView lv;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle tg;

    private String[] fragments;
    private CharSequence tl; //titulo principal
    private CharSequence tlf; //titulo fragment


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_drawerlayout);  
        init();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            selectedItem(0);
        }
    }

    private void init(){
        //actionbar
        onConfigActionBar();
        //listview
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        fragments = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itens_menu_string);
        lv.setAdapter(new DrawerLayoutListViewAdapter(this, fragments));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);        
        //drawerlayout
        dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //actionbardrawertoggle
        tg = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, R.drawable.btmenu, R.string.nomeActionBar){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tl);                
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                ab.setTitle(tlf);
                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };      
        dl.setDrawerListener(tg);

        tl = tlf = getTitle();      
    }

    /** ativa actionbar e botao home na action bar */
    private void onConfigActionBar(){
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        tg.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tg.syncState();
    }

    /** necessario */
     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {           
        if (tg.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }            
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }


     /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.custom_drawer_layout, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /** necessario */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean status = dl.isDrawerOpen(lv);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!status);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
        selectedItem(position);     
    }

    /** seleciona o fragment q sera usado */
    private void selectedItem(int position){
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        Fragment frag;
        switch(position){
            case 0:
                frag = new PerfilFrag();
                ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag);
                ft.commit();
                break;
        }
        lv.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setCustomTitle(fragments[position]);
        dl.closeDrawer(lv);
    }

    private void setCustomTitle(String title){
        ab.setTitle(title);
        tl = title;
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.williarts.batalhajuridica/br.com.williarts.batalhajuridica.draw.CustomDrawerLayout}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at br.com.williarts.batalhajuridica.draw.CustomDrawerLayout.init(CustomDrawerLayout.java:65)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at br.com.williarts.batalhajuridica.draw.CustomDrawerLayout.onCreate(CustomDrawerLayout.java:36)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
11-27 18:57:50.540: E/AndroidRuntime(31167):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your error is a NullPointerException, it can only be that one of the two things is null. Either `dl` is null, or `tg` is null. `tg` doesn't appear to be null, so I'm convinced that it must be `dl`.

Your issue is probably stemming from this line:

```
dl = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Go into your XML and make sure that the layout has the id name "drawer_layout", then check that you're setting the right layout. Basically, that's probably your error.